# Jquery add tag inside a blockquote before a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this text inside a blockquote:

```
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
4 Text<br />
20 TExt<br />
2 Another text a little longer<br />
<br />
20 text</blockquote>
```

I want to add for each line a  tag or convert the br to include a class. if the br was including all the line i would know how to do it. This is how i want to end like:

```
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
<strike>4 Text</strike><br/>
<strike>20 TExt</strike><br/>
<strike>2 Another text a little longer</strike><br/>
<br />
<strike>20 text</strike></blockquote>
```

or

```
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
<br class="X">4 Text<br>
<br class="X">20 TExt<br>
<br class="X">2 Another text a little longer<br>
<br />
<br class="X"> 20 text</br></blockquote>
```

I've tried with wrap but with no sucess, any way to do this?

Comment: Please notice that `<br />` is a self-enclosing tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by manipulating the inner HTML of the blockquote.

```
$('.tr_bq').each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var newHtml = html.split('<br>').map(function (str) {
        return '<strike>' + str + '</strike>';
    }).join('<br>');
    $(this).html(newHtml);
});
```

Comment: i can understand the code and it seems ok to me, but i've tried with no results.

Comment: @JoséMoreira In which browser? I was trying in Chrome.

Comment: Worked for me in Firefox. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L21zqppx/1/) for a slightly more reusable version of my answer to see it in action. Are you sure you are using jQuery like your tag suggests? Your own solution below does not use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a plain-JavaScript means of achieving this, avoiding the (unnecessary) use of a library:

```
function wrapNodesWith(nodes, tag) {
  // if we have neither nodes to wrap, nor a tag to wrap
  // them with, we quit here:
  if (!nodes || !tag) {
    return false;
  }

  // otherwise:

  // we convert the nodes to an array (using Array.prototype.slice,
  // in conjunction with Function.prototype.call):
  nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes, 0);

  // if the tag parameter passed to the function is a string ('strike'),
  // we create that element using document.createElement(tag),
  // otherwise we assume we've got an HTMLElement (this is a very
  // naive check) and so we use that:
  tag = 'string' === typeof tag ? document.createElement(tag) : tag;

  // an unitialised variable for use within the following forEach:
  var clone;

  nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    // n is the node over which we're iterating,

    // cloning the tag (to avoid multiple calls
    // to document.createElement):
    clone = tag.cloneNode();

    // setting the textContent of the clone to the nodeValue
    // of the node (if it's a textNode), or to the textContent of
    // element (again a simple check):
    clone.textContent = n.nodeType === 3 ? n.nodeValue : n.textContent;

    // replacing the childNode, using parentNode.replaceChild(),
    // inserting clone and removing n:
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, n);
  });

}

// finding the first <blockquote> element:
var blockquote = document.querySelector('blockquote'),
    // creating an array of the childNodes of the <blockquote>:
    children = Array.prototype.slice.call(blockquote.childNodes, 0),
    // filtering the children array, retaining only those nodes for
    // which the assessment returns true:
    textNodes = children.filter(function(n) {
      return n.nodeType === 3;
    });

// can be called with:
wrapNodesWith(textNodes, 'strike');

// or:
wrapNodesWith(textNodes, document.createElement('strike'));
```

```js
function wrapNodesWith(nodes, tag) {
  if (!nodes || !tag) {
    return false;
  }

  nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes, 0);
  tag = 'string' === typeof tag ? document.createElement(tag) : tag;

  var parent, clone;

  nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    clone = tag.cloneNode();
    clone.textContent = n.nodeType === 3 ? n.nodeValue : n.textContent;
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, n);
  });

}

var blockquote = document.querySelector('blockquote'),
  children = Array.prototype.slice.call(blockquote.childNodes, 0),
  textNodes = children.filter(function(n) {
    return n.nodeType === 3;
  });

wrapNodesWith(textNodes, 'strike');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
  4 Text
  <br />20 TExt
  <br />2 Another text a little longer
  <br />
  <br />20 text
</blockquote>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).

Comment: Well, i don't know if i'm implementing it wrongly, but it didn't seemed to work.

Comment: Does it work for you in the included snippet? And how are you using it, can you link me to a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/) demo to show me?

Comment: in the included snippet it works, but after that i managed to get a way to work with javascript alone. But thanks for your time nevertheless, it was useful.

Comment: I'm glad you've got it working, whatever 'it' is, in context. If you didn't use a posed answer, it would be interesting to see your own answer to your problem.

Comment: Extremely well explained, sir. Though I would have hidden your snippet code since you include it above the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

i managed to get it working with this:

```
   var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote'),pl = pre.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < pl; i++) {
     var pro = pre[i].innerHTML.split(/<br>/), pz = pro.length;
     pre[i].innerHTML = '';
     for (var a=0; a < pz ; a++) {
     pre[i].innerHTML += '<strike>' + pro[a] + '</strike><br/>';
     }
    }
```